# Remove empty directories in AIX

Tags: find, aix, directory

Is there an easy way to find and remove all empty directories under a specific path? Since -empty is not available in AIX find command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this link](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/58210-removing-empty-folders-using-find-command.html) or [this link](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/49739-how-find-empty-folders-without-using-empty.html) for possibilities.

Also can you use GNU find, installed as part of the linux toolbox in `/opt/freeware/bin/find` or `/usr/linux/bin/find`?   For one offs, I use them quite often on AIX5.2+.  As part of a script or tool I wouldn't rely on them however...

Answer (score 0):

The question applies to all versions of UNIX that don't support the (non-standard) "-empty" qualifier.

The first link in the answer above mentions the "-exec" options, however that would require a fork() / exec() for each and every directory, which can be a bit much.  A far easier solution would be to use xargs and rmdir.  One caveat -- if there are files with special characters in the file name, it can confuse xargs if you don't use the "-print0" option to "find" and the "-0" option to "xargs".

A better and faster solution would be

find  -type d -depth -print0 | xargs --null rmdir

assuming your "find" and "xargs" commands support the non-standard options that are given.